# How to rename 100s of images from the div element title?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, dom

I have a static website which has 1000s of images in tile mode and each image containing a title div.

Is it possible to rename all the files  according to the title div via some php/javascript? If yes, which language shall I use? and what would be the procedure?

each row has 3 divs and each divs containing class:

```
.col-left, .col-middle, .col-right
```

and each div containing a

```
<p> where the title lies.< /p>
```

Now how do I can grab this p (paragraph) element and rename the image file that is within the `.col-left, .col-middle, .col-right` divs.

I have 1000s of rows of images like this, so it's really difficult to track all the images and title name and upload it into new site.

```html
My code is similar to this:

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-left">
 <img src="images/1.jpg">
 <p>Title of my first image</p>
</div>
<div class="col-middle">
 <img src="images/2.jpg">
 <p>Title of my second image</p>

</div>
<div class="col-right">
 <img src="images/3.jpg">
 <p>Title of my third image</p>
</div>
</div>
```

All i want is to RENAME the IMAGES(filename, not the source in html), 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg to Title of my first image.jpg, Title of my second image.jpg, Title of my third image.jpg, and so on, which is located into a folder named images.

It was my first question, so i was not sure how to snippet codes and etc. I am sorry to everyone if my question was not very clear to you.

Comment: how do you want to rename those images (what should they read after the change)? can you provide at least one example of the html structure of the images? anything you tried?

Comment: do you want to have this frequently changed in front of the user's eyes, like a carousel, or just change it one time?

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to rename the files in the server's filesystem, you sould use AJAX and PHP. Something like:

Given the markup

```
<div class="col-left"><p>the title</p><img src="the image"></div>
<div class="col-middle"><p>the title</p><img src="the image"></div>
<div class="col-right"><p>the title</p><img src="the image"></div>
<div class="col-left"><p>the title</p><img src="the image"></div>
<div class="col-middle"><p>the title</p><img src="the image"></div>
<div class="col-right"><p>the title</p><img src="the image"></div>
```

jQuery (you could do it in plain js as well)

```
$(".col-left,.col-middle,.col-right").each(function() {
    $.get("rename.php",{img:$(this).children("img").attr("src"),title:$(this).children("p").text()});
});
```

rename.php

```
$img=$_GET['img']; //VALIDATE THE IMAGE NAME AND IT'S PATH
$tit=$_GET['title'];
rename($img,$tit); //Add the propper paths
```

You could easily use the same idea to send a bunch of images each time to rename.php in order to reduce the number of requests.

Comment: Wow, that's an excellent solution, i will  give it a try. Thanks @Gabriel

Comment: you are an angel man! you have saved my month's work! It worked like a champ! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to answer without actually seeing your HTML. Something like this may work.

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(i=0; i<divs.length; i++){
        var newName = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML;
        var file = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;
        renameFile(newName, file);
}

function renameFile(newName, fn) {
        filename = new String(fn).substring(fn.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        var fso, f;
        fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        f = fso.GetFile(fn);
        f.name = newName;
}
```